# Overriding error Java, program does not read both methods only one

Tags: java, class, object, overriding

I have this code

```
public class Student extends Person {
    //id represents the student's ID
    private int id;
    //grade represents the student's grade in the course
    private Grade grade;

    //constructor allows user to define first and last names, id, and grade of student in demo
    public Student(String fName, String lName, int id, Grade grade) {
        super(fName, lName);
        this.id=id;
        this.grade=grade;
    }
    //get methods for fields
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Grade getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    //toString prints out the string from person class along with id and grade fields in formatted string
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+"'s id is " + id + "." +getGrade();
    }
}
```

And this code. The issue is **where toString method uses the passFailGrade getGrade() return value instead of the method located within the class**

```
public class Grade {

    private double score;

    public Grade(double score) {
        this.score=score;
    }
    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score=score;
    }
    public double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public char getGrade() {
        if (getScore()>=90)
            return 'A';
        else if (getScore()>=80)
            return 'B';
        else if (getScore()>=70)
            return 'C';
        else if (getScore()>=60)
            return 'D';
        else
            return 'F';
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "\nThe student recieved a " + getGrade() + 
                " and had a mark of " + getScore() + ".";
    }
}
```

Not sure if there's a problem in `PassFailGrade`:

```
public class PassFailGrade extends Grade {

    public PassFailGrade(double score) {
        super(score);
    }
    public char getGrade() {
        if (getScore()>=50)
            return 'Y';
        else
            return 'N';
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(Y for yes/N for no) The student passed their course (" 
                + getGrade()+ ")." + super.toString();
    }
}
```

Then demo class just defining in constructors and printing

```
public class StudentDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassFailGrade bo= new PassFailGrade(98);
        Student s1 = new Student("bob", "blake", 123, bo);
        System.out.println(s1); 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
bob blake's id is 123.(Y for yes/N for no) The student passed their course (Y). The student recieved a Y and had a mark of 98.0.
```

Comment: Can you name which is `PassFailGrade ` class and which is `Student ` class ?

Comment: student class is a broader class which defines name, and has a getGrade() in the tostring

Comment: You showed two `getGrade` methods ? Which belong to which class ?

Comment: passfailgrade class and grade class passfailgrade is an extension of grade

Comment: Can you add class signature to the above code you shared so that we can understand your code better ?

Comment: I'll show all my codes,

Comment: @gucci If your came from a `C++` background, just remember all methods in `Java` are `virtual`.

Comment: My problem is that my methods getGrade() are not working together as two different methods, but instead the method in grade.java is returning the getGrade() value from passfailGrade when that is an extension of grade.java

Comment: So what I did was use a variable for the returns statements in getGrade of grade and then I defined that variable as a private field at the top of my code, so the tostring would recognise it.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually **overriding** the `getGrade()` method.  It's something you intended to do, but now you've got a problem when you call `super.toString()` - it *still* uses your overriden methods.

You can fix this issue by changing your `toString` in `PassFailGrade` in this way:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "(Y for yes/N for no) The student passed their course ("
            + getGrade()+ ")." + "\nThe student recieved a " + super.getGrade() +
            " and had a mark of " + getScore() + ".";
}
```

Note that I only call `super.getGrade()`.  This will produce the correct results.

Comment: thank you, I actually made errors in my code, it was wrong sorry for misleading anyone

Comment: I didn't see a problem with your code, actually.  It's a simple mistake that any of us could make.